# OpenXML: How to Copy List of Paragraphs to Template Document

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

Im trying to copy a `List<OpenXmlCompositeElement>` of Paragraphs to a new document, just after the paragraph of a bookmark.  The paragraphs copy, but end up in a seemly random order.  Any ideas?  How do I get them in the correct order

```
    //range is List<OpenXmlCompositeElement>
    foreach (OpenXmlCompositeElement element in range)
    {
        if (element is TableCellProperties){}
        else
        {

           insertionPoint.InsertAfterSelf<OpenXmlCompositeElement>((OpenXmlCompositeElement)element.Clone());

      }
}
```

Comment: Please also show us the code that populates the List?

Comment: Note: I verified that List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> range has the elements in the correct order.  My question is, why doesn't InsertAfterSelf insert them in the correct order?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.  I needed to use the updated OpenXmlCompositeElement object, which is returned by InsertAfterSelf().

```
insertionPoint= insertionPoint.InsertAfterSelf<OpenXmlCompositeElement>((OpenXmlCompositeElement)element.Clone());
```